# The uploaded file could not be moved to wp-content/uploads/2019/07

Tags: uploads

Uploading file at media library getting an error "The uploaded file could not be moved to wp-content/uploads/2019/07.". Please help how it resolves it.

Comment: Please try to change the permission of wp-content folder and let me know if not works.

Comment: I have the same problem.  I tried this and it did not work :(